# PHP displays as plaintext on web server?

Tags: php, html, mysql, github, xampp

I wrote an HTML page using XAMPP on my Windows computer, and everything works great locally. However, I want to host the content on a website, and I have no idea how to do it. [Here it is as is](http://manestay.github.io/), with a PHP code displayed, instead of actually running.

Does github.io support running PHP at all? I read that it doesn't. If so, where would I be able to host my code so that my PHP and JavaScript could run given that I point my browser to the webpage's URL? Also, XAMPP had linked it to an MySql database, but I am unsure of how to set that up as well on a server.

These seem like simple questions for the beginning web developer, but I scoured Google and couldn't find an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Rename it to `index.php`. If github doesn't run it, you'd be best to get hosting for it. If you want cheap hosting, Google is your friend, but Hostgator isn't bad on price either.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy php on the server you have to check:

1. Is there PHP?
2. Take care of pretags
3. Check version of php (it will run with error if php parser is on)
4. Configure your wwwroot or httpdocs or hotdocs (webpage public folder)
5. Take care of .htaccess if something is crashing

And not every server is apache and not every server is node and not every... Just ask support of this hosting because in some cases you have to "turn on" PHP by some fancy button.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

No, [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com) doesn't have PHP, it's only meant to host static pages. It does support Jekyll, a static site generator (in that it generates static pages **once** per push which are then hosted as-is), but that's about all.

PHP/MySQL is only one of the many sets of possible web application technologies, so you can't expect it to be everywhere where web hosting is. It has to be either explicitly listed on hosting service's website, or be available for installation in case you get yourself a full-fledged server machine (maybe virtual) to run your website.

Browser-based JavaScript will still be run by the client, since it's not the server's responsibility to run it, just the delivery. So it **can** be hosted on GitHub Pages. Also, 3rd party services that don't depend on your own server's code execution are usable too: stuff like commenting systems, searches (you can even make a client-side one!) and analytics.